# Thymleaf not returning templates but strings

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm building an application with thymeleaf, and i've encountered this problem where when returning a template as for example ...`return "products";`... and when I visit the url i addressed in `@GetMapping()` i get the string "products" instead of rendered template

[image].

[image]

```
@Service
public class HomeService {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    public String getProducts(Model model) {
        List<Product> products= productRepository.findAll();

        if (!products.isEmpty()){
            model.addAttribute("product", products);
            return "products";
        }else{
            return "404";
        }
    }
}

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    HomeService homeService;

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(Model model){
        return homeService.getProducts(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: in order to return a view (i.e a Thymeleaf template) from your controller, replace RestController with Controller. I suggest that you read this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated above, the @RestController annotation should be replaced with the @Controller annotation.

The @RestController annotation in Spring is designed for building REST web services that return data in JSON or XML format, and it does not support the use of view templating engines like Thymeleaf. If you want to render HTML views, you should use the @Controller. In @Controller, we can return a view in Spring Web MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Controller, @RestController is for RestAPI only, and not MVC